# What to make out of this.....?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, work

Let's set up an experiment first.
Suppose there is a body of rest mass $m$ at rest in an observers inertial frame and it is accelerated to almost $c$ (speed of light) at constant acceleration $a$ with respect to the observer (meaning variable force since mass is variable).
Work done by the variable forces will be:

$$\int_0^{c/a}\frac{ma}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}dx$$ $$=\int_0^{c/a}\frac{ma}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2t^2}{c^2}}}{atdt}$$ $$=\frac12\int_0^{c/a}\frac{ma^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2t^2}{c^2}}}{dt^2}$$ $$=\frac12ma^2\frac{\left[\frac{\left(1-\frac{a^2t^2}{c^2}\right)^{-\frac12+1}}{-\frac12+1}\right]}{-\frac{a^2}{c^2}}$$ $$=-\frac12mc^2\times2\left[0-1\right]$$ $$=mc^2$$

My questions:

1. What I did is it correct if not what did I do wrong?
2. if what I did is correct then how to interpret the value of work done via intuition?
3. if what I did is correct then isn't this the violation of work energy theorem W = ∆KE since finally KE is infinite for the observer but work is finite.

Comment: Your mass cannot be accelerated to $c$ as no massive object can travel at the speed of light.

Comment: KE=$$\frac{\Delta (mv^2)}{2}$$ probably you are ignoring the *Mass* factor for KE.

Comment: No mass is included that's why KE is coming infinite.

Comment: The result won't change even if I make it a limiting case for the speed tending to c.

Comment: @Steve i guess you mean 0 mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My questions:

> What I did is it correct if not what did I do wrong?

No, it is not correct.

The work is equal to the change in kinetic energy. If the particle starts at rest the change in kinetic energy [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_mechanics):
$$
(\gamma - 1)m_0 c^2
$$

Therefore, infinite work would be required to accelerate the particle to the speed of light. Which makes sense, since no massive particle can travel at the speed of light.

Comment: Umm yeah I asked this in my third question but what is wrong basically I want to know that since my math looks correct ,at least to me. Also I don't see any problem in the hypothetical experiment ,if there is can you highlight it.

Comment: You used the wrong expression for the work. It is the integral of m$\gamma^3$vdv

Comment: You seem to be integrating ma$\gamma$dx, but not clear why you think this is the correct starting point. Your starting point is wrong.

Comment: I assume you are saying Fdx = ma(y)vdt = m(y)vdv I don't see why will there be ( y)^3 in the integral

Comment: At speed v force F would be m(y)a so dw = F.dx = Fdx = m(y) a dx

Comment: No, the force F = dp/dt, where p=m$\gamma$v. This is not equal to m$\gamma$a, since you have to differentiate gamma. (It is equal to m$\gamma^3$a. (You have to use the product rule and rearrange the terms a bit.))

Comment: Thanks I understood what I was doing wrong I was ignoring the thrust force due to the continuous change in mass ie I was assuming subconsciously that at any instant mass is remaining constant ie dm/dt = 0 . After  integrating the new integrand result is still finite and is equal to -ve of the work calculated in the OP but logically work should not be -ve here so how can we interpret that .

Comment: I'm sorry, what you are saying does not make sense to me. In my notation (and in your notation) the mass $m$ is the rest mass. The rest mass does not change with time.

Comment: mb I didn't clarify dp/dt = mdv/dt + vdm/dt here m is not the rest mass rather it is mass of the body at any general time and therefore vdm/dt = vMdγ/dt (here M is the rest mass)

Comment: OK, but in your posted question, you said "rest mass m" (lowercase m).